# Remix.run static asset return 404

Tags: remix.run

I am hitting a brick wall trying to display an image with remix.run.

The documentation on Asset Preloads shows the following:

[image]

When I do this I am getting a 404 for the /icons/clipboard.svg.  Do I need to add a route to get static assets to route properly?

Another example is the Jokes tutorial.  I add an assets folder under app with a file `heart.svg`.  From my jokes.jsx, I add `<img src="/assets/heart.svg"/>` which 404's, along with `"~/assets/heart.svg"` or `"../assets/heart.svg"`

I am thinking there is something glaring me in the face that I am missing here, an additional route, build param, something...

Comment: Another option is to import them. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015461/how-to-load-svg-components-in-remix-run-application/72928536#72928536).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out.  Gotta put the asset folder in the public folder for it to get hit.  Moving it out of the app folder into public resolved my issue.

Comment: Hey, glad you figured it out yourself  If it's completely resolved you could mark your question as solved 